# Ordering the X-axis in R graph

Tags: r, matrix, plot, graph

I have a matrix named "gvs" of 52 numbers:

```
 [1,] -2.3321916
 [2,] -1.4996229
 [3,]  1.7958170
 [4,]  2.5543214
 [5,] -2.7758460
 [6,] -1.9659984
 [7,]  2.1239768
 [8,] -1.8515908
 [9,] -1.5597359
[10,] -1.2534511
[11,] -0.1625003
[12,] -1.0265275
[13,] -0.8519079
[14,] -2.4279528
[15,] -3.1717421
[16,] -0.9258497
[17,] -1.2207974
[18,] -1.0325107
[19,] -3.2102686
[20,] -0.9377928
[21,] -1.7657017
[22,] -0.5058627
[23,] -0.7819299
[24,] -1.4095947
[25,]  2.2810477
[26,] -0.9007551
[27,]  2.6614486
[28,] -0.9441980
[29,] -0.7237586
[30,] -0.9452944
[31,] -1.2035258
[32,] -0.7703779
[33,] -3.0895998
[34,] -0.7037952
[35,] -1.9311354
[36,] -0.5423822
[37,] -1.6244801
[38,] -0.9049735
[39,] -2.6491331
[40,]  2.3706977
[41,] -2.7590587
[42,] -0.9614190
[43,] -1.6961014
[44,] -0.8449225
[45,] -1.1163019
[46,] -0.9298674
[47,] -2.8859587
[48,] -1.4494841
[49,] -0.7381369
[50,] -0.5644325
[51,] -0.9195156
[52,]  2.0949378
```

I would like to plot the numbers in a specific order across the x-axis. I want to plot the numbers in a certain order such as this along the x-axis

```
1
5
15
19
33
39
41
47
6
14
31
35
2
8
9
17
21
24
37
43
48
10
12
13
16
18
20
23
29
30
32
34
42
45
46
49
50
51
11
22
26
38
44
28
36
3
4
7
25
27
40
52.
```

I also have a .txt file with 52 words that hopefully I could use as a label for the graph along the x-axis for each point here:

```
Adygei
Basque
French
Italian
Orcadian
Russian
Sardinian
Tuscan
Bedouin
Druze
Mozabite
Palestinian
Balochi
Brahui
Burusho
Hazara
Kalash
Makrani
Pathan
Sindhi
Uygurf
Cambodian
Dai
Daur
Han
Hezhen
Japanese
Lahu
Miao
Mongola
Naxi
Oroqen
She
Tu
Tujia
Xibo
Yakut
Yi
Colombian
Karitiana
Maya
Pima
Surui
Melanesian
Papuan
BantuKenya
BantuSouthAfrica
BiakaPygmy
Mandenka
MbutiPygmy
San
Yoruba
```

I would like to plot the matrix `gvs` along the x-axis in the order of the second file, with the third file being the labels. The .txt file is already in the proper order. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: first off, store the three objects in a single `data.frame` (or `data.table`)

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: It seems you may be in a bit over your head. Check out the [tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) and read some tutorials/intros